# amcharts: reverse time (category) axis?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, amcharts

Is it possible to reverse the category axis of a time-based chart in amcharts? I know that the value axis can be easily flipped but I've not seen a solution for the category axis. I need to have the most relevant and therefore recent data on the left.

I'm using a time-based area chart. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N5rpu/1/

In the example I've reversed the value axis and done the same to the category axis just to show that nothing happens.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "none",
    "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "position": "left",
        "title": "Unique visitors",
        "reversed": true
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "fillAlphas": 0.4,
        "valueField": "visits"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {},
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN, DD MMMM",
        "cursorPosition": "mouse"
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "minPeriod": "mm",
        "parseDates": true,
        "reversed": true
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I had the opposite problem - dates in the AmCharts categoryAxis where being displayed in reverse from chronological order!

This was achieved by ordering the dates from most recent to less recent in the dataProvider array, i.e.

```
  "dataProvider": [{
      "value": 74,
      "date": "2014-11-16"
    },
    {
      "value": 73,
      "date": "2014-11-15"
    },
    {
      "value": 70,
      "date": "2014-11-14"
    }];
```

Comment: One note, for this to work you must set "parseDates" to false (the default), then in order to format dates do that manually with chart "categoryFunction". Updated demo here http://jsfiddle.net/pfitzgerald/12ampu3f/2/